# Своя метка и caption

Tags: yandex-maps-api, yandex-maps-jsapi

Возможно ли создать свою метку caption подобно указанной на скриншоте?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В API карт нельзя кастомизировать внешний вид подписи метки, но можно кастомизировать весь макет метки. Через опцию iconLayout можно задать свой html-макет. Чтобы сместить метку относительно точки надо в html-макете сделать смещение в определенную сторону через абсолютно позиционирование или css-transform. В примере ниже как раз обычный pos:abs используется.

Пример в песочнице: https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.1/placemark_shape

Comment: А в той ссылке что вы дали подробно описано как создать метку со стилями. А вы говорите что задумка автора не может быть реализовано. Или я что то не правильно понял?

Comment: Ну наверное я не совсем правильно выразился. В API карт есть сущность caption (подпись метки) у стандартного макета метки. Его нельзя кастомизировать - только текст задать. Но можно настроить внешний вид всей метки.

Comment: Просто как то не понятен вопрос автора, там цифры что эначят? И кто их задаёт?

Comment: Как я понял, вопрос именно про возможность отобразить подпись метки определенным образом. Контент не так важен.

Comment: Цифры означают стоимость. В данном случае "M" - означает Million. А "units" - это количество квартир в доме. Задается стоимость при формировании json-описаний объектов.